# Multiple page ids in an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm fairly new to PHP so go easy.

```
<?php 
$body_classes = get_body_class();
$ScanL="url";
if(in_array('parent-pageid-385', $body_classes))
{
  echo '<img src="'. $ScanL.'/images/product-logos/image1.gif" />';
}

else if(in_array('parent-pageid-394', $body_classes)) {
  echo '<img src="'. $ScanL.'/images/product-logos/image2.gif" />';
}

else if(in_array('parent-pageid-238', $body_classes)) {
  echo '<img src="'. $ScanL.'/images/product-logos/image3.gif" />';
}

else if(in_array('parent-pageid-382', $body_classes)) {
  echo '<img src="'. $ScanL.'/images/product-logos/image4.gif" />';
}

else if(in_array('page-id-391', $body_classes)) {
  echo '<img src="'. $ScanL.'/images/product-logos/image5.gif" />';
}

else if (in_array('page-id-334', $body_classes)) {
  echo '<img src="'. $ScanL.'/images/product-logos/image6.gif" />';
}

if(in_array('parent-pageid-385', $body_classes))
```

I need the above to be applied to more than one page id - I tried adding , '' but that broke the code and also tried or / ||

I'm sure I'm probably missing something obvious.

Thanks,

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is the code you tried to add?

Comment: `if (in_array($a, $arr) || in_array($b, $arr) || in_array($c, $arr))`

Comment: whats the problem here?